# What do the width and height attributes do when using srcset and sizes?

Tags: html, css, responsive-images

If we're using the `srcset` and `sizes` attributes, it is still useful to specify a `src` attribute as a fallback. Similarly, I imagine that older browsers would also take advantage of `width` and `height` attributes if they were specified. But do modern browsers?

For example:

```
<img
   src="foo100x100.jpg"
   srcset="foo100x100.jpg 100w, foo500x500.jpg 500w, foo900x900 900w"
   sizes="100vw"
   width="100"
   height="100"
   alt="example"
>
```

Are the `width` and `height` attributes of any use to a modern browser in this example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on experimentation, it behaves as if you had specified `width` and `height` CSS properties in pixels. However, it can be overridden by your own CSS.

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  /* height will be 100px because of the HTML attribute */
}
```

```html
<img
     src="http://placehold.it/100x100"
     srcset="http://placehold.it/100x100 100w, http://placehold.it/500x500 500w"
     sizes="100vw"
     alt=""
     width="100"
     height="100"
>
```

This is a bit disappointing, as I was hoping that modern browsers would use `width` and `height` HTML attributes to determine what the aspect ratio of the image was before downloading the image, so as to avoid the layout of following content jumping around as the page loads.